# How set stmp unsing native function MAIL in PHP

Tags: php, smtp

I'm trying to put a smtp in a source of php. Today SMTP is coming with a different domain name, so i'm trying to change the name of the smtp using(init_set) this below:

**today is: hw102.test.com.br** (example)

**i need to change to: mail.mydomain.com**

```
ini_set ("SMTP", "mail.mydomain.com.br");
```

but not work.

When it arrives in my email comes with smtp "hw102.test.com.br". I want to come with this  smtp "mail.mydomain.com.br".

I need to change something in php.ini too?

Anybody here can help me?

Comment: What operating system are you running php on?

Comment: The `SMTP` directive is only used on windows systems. I would recommend using PHPMailer. See this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11942896/use-default-php-mail-function-with-smtp-server-on-linux) for more information.

Comment: There's no way then use ini_set on my php page on linux right? I have to redo my code, is this?

Comment: Usually linux servers, by default, have an smtp server installed with the `sendmail` command so trying to set an smtp server on linux is unnecessary.  I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  Do you want the `from` domain to be `mail.domain.com.br`? If so you can set this but by modifying the `sendmail_path` directive to something like `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fusername@mail.mydomain.com.br -Fusername`.

Comment: Though you won't be able to set this directive using `ini_set`, as it can only be set in `php.ini` or `httpd.conf`

Comment: I want change this: mailed-by: hw102.test.com.br 
its a smpt who sended.